# Gradle build fails in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I am using Android Studio and created a new project, which created the standard "Hello world" mock.

My `gradle.build` file has the following contents:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatever.blabla"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Even though I did not change anything, Gradle still fails when trying to build it with the error:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

First of all, is there any way of getting extra info about the problem? And secondly, why is this happening since I only created a standard project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and could fix it by following solution provided in the below link -
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67946

Though I am not sure how setting the maxheapsize has fixed the issue.